# Adding HSTS Header in Swagger index.html

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

Our Rest API was pen tested and a HSTS error came back ONLY on the index.html that swagger generates.

It's a .net core 6 REST Api, and the endpoints all return a valid response, it's solely on the swagger generated index.html.

In my program.cs I have the following that sets it up:

```
internal static void SetupSecurity(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration = services
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetConfigurationData<SecurityConfiguration>();

        if (securityConfiguration.UseSSL)
        {
            services
                .AddHsts(options =>
                {
                    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(securityConfiguration.MaxAge);
                })
                .AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
                {
                    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
                    options.HttpsPort = securityConfiguration.HttpsPort;
                });
        }
    }
```

and in my program.cs this is called by doing services.SetupSecrity ad app.SetupSecurity, but this is only applying to the endpoints and not the swagger html (which makes sense).

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, what's the best solution to fix it? I can't seem to find anywhere that will let me inject the html page swagger generates to add the relevant response header.

I can't just add it in IIS, as then the endpoints return multiple headers which doesn't seem correct to do. I could remove it from code completely, but that would lead to lots of tech support to update customers' installations.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question shows how the necessary services are being configured and registered. It's the order of how these get applied in the ASP.NET pipeline that matters here.

Make sure that you have a call to [app.UseHsts()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.hstsbuilderextensions.usehsts) before calling `UseSwaggerUI`.

From the documentation

> Adds middleware for using HSTS, which adds the Strict-Transport-Security header.

```
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// ....

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

// ...
```